# Define two findOne on one method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have error when i define findOne using mongoose like this,

```
Nodes.findOne({label: req.decoded.username}, function(err, node){
      Skema.findOne({_id: node.user}, function(err, user) {
          if (req.body.topic == user.username+'/'+node.label) {
            res.sendStatus(200)
          } else{
            res.sendStatus(403)
          }
      })
    })
```

My mongoose scheme,

```
var userscheme = new Schema({_id : String, user : String,label : String, secretkey : String,subsperday : Number,subsperdayremain : Number, sensor : [{ id : String, label : String}]})

var userskema = new Schema({_id : String,username : String,email : String, password : String,first_name : String,last_name : String,is_admin : Number})

var Nodes = mongoose.model('nodes', userscheme)
var Skema = mongoose.model('user', userskema)
```

When i run my program, i have error `user` variable on `Skema.findOne({_id: node.user}, function(err, user)` return null. When i print `node.user` it's print id like what i want.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Mongoose returning null suggest there is no such user in your database. Is `node` what you expect? `console.log(node);`. Is `node.user` what you expect? `console.log(node.user);` Are you sure it's not `node.user.id` that you want to use? What is your exact error? You can also try the node debugger to see exact values at certain points of your app. https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html

Comment: You probably should be using [mongoose population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) for this. The second query does not return a result because the item is not found. Show the documents you expect to be matched by both statements as they appear in the mongo shell. One of them is probably an `ObjectId` despite your schema definition.

Comment: @ippi There is nothing wrong with the naming since it matches the `Schema` statements given. The exact error ( which actually is not an error ) is as stated in the question. It returns `null`

Comment: @ippi This isn't going anywhere. The OP already said *"When i print node.user it's print id like what i want."* So they clearly are seeing something. I'm waiting for some clarification on what exactly that "something" looks like. So let's just wait for their input.

Comment: Thank's guys, i got the error because i miss some syntax "collection: 'user'" in my second schema.